# Connecting entities to OneToMany and ManyToOne throws errors

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

everyone. I'm trying to connect two entities using Spring Boot JPA (Hibernate), Entries and Friends. Unfortunately I get the following error when deploying in the console:

Error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.home.calendar.Freunde.Freunde.eintraege in com.home.calendar.Eintraege.Eintraege.freunde

Eintraege Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="eintraege")
public class Eintraege {

@JsonIgnoreProperties("eintraege")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "eintraege")
private List<Freunde> freunde;

}
```

Freunde Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Freunde {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "freunde_id")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("freunde")
private Eintraege eintrag;

}
```

Comment: The error message is rather self-explanatory for once, you need `mappedBy = "eintrag"`

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the Freunde field. update Freunde class to `private Eintraege eintraege` or change the `mappedBy` in `Eintraege` class to `mappedBy = "eintrag"`

Further explanation: the `mappedBy = "fieldName"` must match a field in the referred entity. In your case, due to this mismatch, you get your error.